# How can I find missing date range in sql server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My data looks like below.
[image]

How can I find missing date range from ss table.

I want to find missing(ss date range) date range between **se_startdate and se_enddate**.

for example above.

**Missing date ranges are**

```
2014-07-01 to 2014-07-06
2014-07-18 to 2014-07-30.
```

Comment: I have tried using view and using while loop but couldn't get whole logic.

Comment: Similar question: [SQL Query to show gaps between multiple date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604400/sql-query-to-show-gaps-between-multiple-date-ranges)

Comment: Can SS_StartDate be earlier than se_startdate or SS_EndDate be later than se_enddate? In other words - does interval (se_startdate, se_enddate) always include interval (SS_StartDate, SS_EndDate) ?

Comment: yes se_startdate and se_enddate always include ss_startdate and ss_enddate. It can't be outside se_startdate and se_enddate

Comment: Probably worth reading [Gaps and Islands by Itzik Ben-Gan](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a simpler way to do this, but often when trying to find missing numbers/dates you need to create those numbers/dates then `LEFT JOIN` to your existing data to find what is missing. You can create the dates in question with a recursive cte:

```
WITH cal AS (SELECT CAST('2014-07-01' AS DATE) dt
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,dt)
              FROM cal
              WHERE dt < '2014-07-30')
SELECT *
FROM cal
```

Then, you `LEFT JOIN` to your table to get a list of missing dates:

```
WITH cal AS (SELECT CAST('2014-07-01' AS DATE) dt
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,dt)
              FROM cal
              WHERE dt < '2014-07-30')
SELECT DISTINCT cal.dt 
FROM  cal
LEFT JOIN YourTable a
   ON cal.dt BETWEEN CAST(SS_StartDate AS DATE) AND CAST(SS_EndDate AS DATE)
WHERE a.SS_StartDate IS NULL
```

Then you need to find out whether or not consecutive rows belong in the same range, or if they have a gap between them, using `DATEDIFF()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH cal AS (SELECT CAST('2014-07-01' AS DATE) dt
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,dt)
              FROM cal
              WHERE dt < '2014-07-30')
    ,dt_list AS (SELECT DISTINCT cal.dt 
                  FROM  cal
                  LEFT JOIN YourTable a
                    ON cal.dt BETWEEN CAST(SS_StartDate AS DATE) AND CAST(SS_EndDate AS DATE)
                  WHERE a.SS_StartDate IS NULL)        
SELECT dt
      ,DATEDIFF(D, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt), dt) AS dt_range
FROM dt_list
```

Then use `MIN()` and `MAX()` to get the ranges:

```
WITH cal AS (SELECT CAST('2014-07-01' AS DATE) dt
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,dt)
              FROM cal
              WHERE dt < '2014-07-30')
    ,dt_list AS (SELECT DISTINCT cal.dt 
                  FROM  cal
                  LEFT JOIN YourTable a
                    ON cal.dt BETWEEN CAST(SS_StartDate AS DATE) AND CAST(SS_EndDate AS DATE)
                  WHERE a.SS_StartDate IS NULL)        
    ,dt_range AS (SELECT dt
                         ,DATEDIFF(D, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt), dt) AS dt_range
                  FROM dt_list)
SELECT  MIN(dt) AS BeginRange
       ,MAX(dt) AS EndRange
FROM dt_range
GROUP BY dt_range;
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6106/3/0)

Note: If the range you're checking is more than 100 days you'll need to specify the `MAXRECURSION`, 0 means no limit.

Note2: If your `SE` dates are intended to drive the complete date range, then change the `cal` cte from fixed dates to queries using `MIN()` and `MAX()` respectively.

Comment: For what it's worth using a recursive cte to [generate a sequential series](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) is probably the worst way of doing it (explicit loops aside). Also in SQL Server [`NOT EXISTS` will out perform `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/). However, plus 1 still as the logic is spot on.

Comment: @GarethD Good notes, I use `NOT EXISTS` in most situations, but not as often when explaining how to do things to others.  The stacked cte method in the link on sequential series is very clever, I typically use `FROM  master..spt_values v1,master..spt_values v2 ...` but I think I'll switch.

Answer (score 0):

A missing range must start at either se_StartDate or ss_EndDate+1.  Likewise, it must end on either se_EndDate or ss_StartDate-1.  Permute the candidate ranges and discard the overlappers.

The advantage of this method is that the time precision is easily adjustable to hours, or minutes or seconds without needing to enumerate every clock tick.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56b4e/1)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  range_start, range_end, se_StartDate, se_EndDate
FROM MyTable t1
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT se_StartDate range_start
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(day,1,SS_EndDate)
) rs
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT se_EndDate range_end
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,SS_StartDate)
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE
    se_StartDate = t1.se_StartDate AND
    se_EndDate   = t1.se_EndDate AND
    SS_StartDate > range_start
) re
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE
    range_start < SS_EndDate AND
    range_end > SS_StartDate
)
```